# Деление двоичных чисел методом без восстановление остатка

Tags: деление

Я реализовал алгоритм деления для 4 разрядных чисел(беззнаковых).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и все хорошо работает. Но как только делимое у меня становится больше 9. То почему то алгоритм перестает правильно работать. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень срочно нужна помощь
Алгоритм:
Алгоритм вычисления целочисленного частного пары 4-разрядных чисел делением без восстановления частичного остатка сводится к следующим шагам:

- Поместим делимое в регистр A, делитель в регистр B, 0 в регистр P
- Если регистр P отрицательный

o (I-a) Сдвиг пары регистров (P,A) на один бит влево

o (II-a) Добавить содержимое регистра B к P

- Если регистр P положительный

o (I-b) Сдвиг пары регистров (P,A) на один бит влево

o (II-b) Вычесть содержимое регистра B из P

- (III) Если регистр P отрицательный установить 0 на позицию младшего разряда, иначе установить туда 1
- После 4 циклов частное находится в регистре A

Comment: Вставка скриншотов - зло. На планшете/мобильнике глаза сломаешь, автора обматеришь, и плюнешь. В словесной форме по шагам алгоритм опишите, или на языке каком..

Comment: я добавил по вашей просьбе алгоритм

Comment: У вас задача самому алгоритм придумать? По описанию (гораздо лучше!) - (удалил) .. Разглядел по скриншотам, что Р - пятиразрядный, старший разряд знаковый видимо.

Comment: Делить четырехразрядные числа проще быстрее и понятнее с помощью байтовой таблицы 16 на 16.

Comment: Какая-то контрольная работа, похоже... Время вышло, автор убежал :) Числа в скриншоте описанию не соответствуют, гадать лень, я интерес потерял и тоже убежал )

Comment: такой задание, реализовать алгоритм, указанный выше